# Jekyll `where_exp` filter with "contains" expression

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a page for authors for my Jekyll website. On this page, I want to show all the posts that this particular author has written.

This is how my posts look like:

```
title: "Some title"
authors: [author1, author2]
```

For keeping the list of authors, I use collections.

An author looks like that:

```
short: author1
name: "Author 1 Full Name"
```

Now for `author1` I want to find all the articles of this author. I'm trying to use `where_exp` for that:

```
{% assign articles = site.posts | where_exp: "authors", "authors contains page.short" %}
```

In this case, `page.short` contains `author1`.

But the list `articles` is empty. Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax issue in your filter, you can refer to the way it is used [in the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#where-expression).

You can see there that it is used as

```
{{ site.members | where_exp:"item", "item.projects contains 'foo'" }}
```

But in your attempt, you are missing to define what field of the item should the `contains` query.

In the code

```
where_exp:"item", "item.projects contains 'foo'"
```

we do define an `item` out of an array, and then we expect this `item` to have a field `projects`; where we want only the one containing the project `foo`

When in your code

```
where_exp: "authors", "authors contains page.short"
```

You are saying that the `item` is actually called  `authors` and you want the item **itself** to contain `page.short`

A more correct approach would be:

```
site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.authors contains page.short"
```

Because the *items* of your array `site.posts` are actually `posts`, so an *item* of it is a `post`.
Then, on a post, you expect a field `authors`, so `post.authors` to contain a specific string.

Comment: That worked, thanks for the explanation. Now it's clearer